# is it possible to create support multiple screen size in android 3.1 using support library for devices

Tags: android

is it possible to create support multiple screen size in android 3.1 using support library for devices .I have created four layout layout-large layout-small layout-xlarge layout-xlarge design is not coming properly in some device .I have used dp in my layout

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple layout certainly works - how have you named your files and folders?

They must follow naming conventions in order for Android to apply the correct ones.
See [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and in particular, the 'Using configuration qualifiers' section.